# Zoom in & out by javaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make the same functionality of "Ctrl +" & "ctrl -" shortcuts.

how can i do this using javascript?

if it is not valid by javascript is there another options?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's the default behavior for most browsers, what are you trying to do differently?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to activate/trigger the zoom functions from JavaScript.

Comment: Well, I know that if you make the pages use EMs as the dimensions of things you can just scale the font size, but really why would you want to go to the trouble to do this when it isn't going to work as well as the browser

Comment: i just want to make the same functionality but when pressing on button on the screen rather than press " Ctrl + " shortcut.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the zoom level of the browsers via javascript (at least not reliably on all browsers)

but you can emulate the zoom behavior by changing font sizes using javascript and css

Comment: Is there a way to fire the action of "Ctrl +" ?

Comment: you can reakt to key events by adding a handler function to the onKeypress eventhandler, but if your zoom handler gets priority over the system zoom function will be browser and maybe even plattform dependent